# Calculate the Date

Tags: java, android

Friends I am getting two inputs from the user

```
1.InitDate from DatePicker
2.Difference in between two dates (numberOfDates)
```

I need to calculate the FinalDate such that

```
FinalDate=InitDate+numberOfDates
```

What I have done till now

```
private void CalcLastDate(int days) 
        {

long millis=days*24*60*60;

            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

            c.set(settingsFromDate.getYear(), settingsFromDate.getMonth(), settingsFromDate.getDayOfMonth());
            long initDate = c.getTimeInMillis();

            long longFinalDate=initDate+millis;

}
```

Comment: You need to split your day,month and year and add into calendar object after that your can add it.

Comment: hey can you share any snippet/sample ?

Comment: @Nishant  I am not sure how to start ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(initDate); //initDate must be of java.util.Date
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, numberOfDates);
```

You can get the your final date with:

```
Date finalDate = cal.getTime();
```

And you don't have to use a third party api.

Comment: Hey The return type is void . Where is my final Date then ?

Comment: DATE IS  3
 MONTH IS 0
 YEAR IS  113
 finalDATE IS  Wed Jan 30 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2013

Also the calculation is giving me wrong date.
Init Date is 12-10-2012
Diff 1
final DATE IS  Mon Dec 10 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2012

Comment: @onkar I can't follow you. What is the problem?

Comment: The result is not whar is expected, also I am getting wrong year when I am using finalDate.getYear()

Comment: I expected that you are familiar with the java.util.Date class. If not please read the javadoc of the Date class. Besides this, you can also get the year, month and day from the calendar object. Please read the javadoc for this class too.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Joda DateTime library](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/). `DateTime#plusDays` will add days.

```
//Initialize your date
DateTime dateTime = DateTime(...);

dateTime.plusDays(days);
```

Very easy to handle date and this library will be added to Java 8.

Comment: +1 for Joda Time. However the Dalvik runtime on Android (currently) is comparable to Java 6 SE. So the Joda Time library must always be supplied with the application.

Answer (score 0):

you could probably do something similar to this.

```
private DatePicker initPicker;
dp = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.initPicker);
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR,initPicker.getYear());
    c.setMonth(Calendar.MONTH,initPicker.getMonth());
    c.setDayOfMonth(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,initPicker.getDayOfMonth());
long millis = c.getTimeInMillis();
```

For the different date picker objects. then add or subtract the millis in what ever sequence you need.